# Can C++ GRPC be called in Go?

Tags: grpc

I have a Client/Server implementation already done and written in C++ for one project.

I'm starting a new project in Go making a web app and I want it to interact with the server implementation that I did in C++. Is there a way I can re use the C++ client implementation and call that from my Go code or will I just have to rewrite the client code in Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to implement this is by turning your client into a locally running server.  To do this, you can make a wrapper proto file, that will generate code for both C++ and Go.  Implement the stubs in C++ as wrappers to the real function, and then call the stubs from your gRPC Go client.  In effect, you are chaining the calls.